# How to filter-out and print only rows that have field with a specific value using csv.DictReader?

Tags: python, csv

I am reading a CSV file in Python.

```
with open('file.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row['id'], row['first_name'], row['last_name'], row['state'])
```

How can I add some code to filter out and print only rows for a specific "State"? I mean the program will ask the user which state they want to print and print only rows (include also "id", "first_name", "last_name") for a specific state that the user wants.

I can not use Pandas or Numpy libraries.

Comment: Did you try using an if statement before the print?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using a [list comprehension](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/). Note that we first load all records here and then filter. Other solutions propose to filter *while* loading the file.

```py
import csv

def filter_by_state(rows, target_state):
    return [row for row in rows if row['state'] == target_state]

with open('file.csv') as f:
    # This loads all records into memory and closes the CSV file afterwards
    rows = list(csv.DictReader(f))
rows = filter_by_state(rows, 'OK')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if row['state'] == something:
    print(row['id'], row['first_name'], row['last_name'], row['state'])
```

should work, if you want the user to choose, let him modify the variable "something" to what he want

Answer (score 1):

With the method `input()` you ask for the user input (the needed state).
With the `if` statement you control the printed output.

```
with open('file.csv', newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        user_state = input('Enter the searched state')
        for row in reader:
            if user_state == row['state']:
                 print(row['id'], row['first_name'], row['last_name'], row['state'])
```